# Jquery file upload / Rails - File being submitted twice, once to correct url, once to current url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

The following code works and save the file correctly, however it posts twice. Once to /attachments (which is the desired URL), and once to the current path /sections (which is not the desired path). If I uncomment

```
url: "attachments"
```

then it submits twice to /attachments, once with attachment, attached_type_type, and attached_type_id (which is the desired information), and once with just the attachment data.

How can I just get the initial POST and not the second part?

Form:

```
<%= form_for @attachment do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :attached_item_id, value: section.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :attached_item_type, value: "Section" %>
    <%= f.label :attachment, "Upload a file" %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :attachment, name: "attachment[attachment]", class: "new_attachment" %>   
<% end %>

<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
  <div class="upload">
  {%=o.name%}
</script>
```

JS:

```
var file_upload = function() {
  $('.new_attachment').fileupload({
    dataType: "script",
    // url: 'attachments',
    add: function(e, data) {
      var file, types;
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;
      file = data.files[0];
      if (types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)) {
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file));
        $('#new_attachment').append(data.context);
        return data.submit();
        return false;
      } else {
        return alert(file.name + " is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file");
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because your input file is part of the form, try creating an input without f.file_field.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't understand your answare: without f.file_field the form_for doesn't act, Behind form_for there is a "create" action in a controller ...¿? Thanks